# Solving complex equations with variable exponents

Tags: equation-solving, complex

How would I go about solving

$(1+i)^n = (1+\sqrt{3}i)^m$ for integer $m$ and $n$?

I have tried

```
Solve[(1+I)^n == (1+Sqrt[3] I)^m && n ∈ Integers && m ∈ Integers, {n, m}]
```

but this does not give the answer in the 'correct' form.

Comment: You have two unknowns and one equation, is there a solution for both n and m?

Comment: I don't think Mathematica can solve this directly, when written in this form.  But this should give a hint about the solution:  `Table[Through[{Re, Im}[(1 + I)^n]], {n, 0, 50, 4}]` and `Table[Through[{Re, Im}[(1 + Sqrt[3] I)^m]], {m, 0, 50, 3}]`.  (`n==24 && m==12` is one possible solution.)

Comment: @JasonB  Actually, there are two equations, one for the amplitudes and the other for the phases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the question and also the comment above by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs), Mathematica does not seem to be able to solve the equation directly.  For instance, neither `Solve` nor `Reduce` produces the desired result.  However, as I suggested in a comment above, the equation can be decomposed into expressions for its amplitude and phase, and each solved to obtain the answer.  Begin with the amplitude.

```
Abs[(1 + I)]^n == Abs[(1 + Sqrt[3] I)]^m
(* 2^(n/2) == 2^m *)
```

Thus, `n` is twice `m`.  Insert this into the expression for the phases, modulo `2 π`.

```
Solve[(Mod[Arg[(1 + I)] n, 2 π] == 
    Mod[Arg[(1 + Sqrt[3] I)] m, 2 π]) /. n -> 2 m, m, Integers]
(* {{m -> ConditionalExpression[12 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}} *)
```

This, `m` is any integer, positive or negative, multiplied by `12`, and `n` is `2 m`.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting how this seems to be the only way without resorting to a brute force search (see the other answers). I was thinking there would be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 6):

One can get a truly ridiculous solution by `ComplexExpand[]`ing the real and imaginary parts:

```
Reduce[ComplexExpand[{Re /@ #, Im /@ #}] &[
    (1 + I)^n == (1 + Sqrt[3] I)^m], 
  {m, n}, Integers]
(*  ... an astonishing mess involving 14 integer parameters ... *)
```

However, pulling out the magnitude and argument is much nicer.

```
Reduce[ComplexExpand[{Abs /@ #, Arg /@ #}] &[
    (1 + I)^n == (1 + Sqrt[3] I)^m], 
  {m, n}, Integers]
(* C[1] ∈ Integers && m == 12 C[1] && n == 24 C[1] *)
```

(This essentially automates [@bbgodfrey's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104311/16237).)

Comment: That's the way how to solve such equations! +1:)

Answer (score 4):

```
Last@Reap@Do[
  If[
   ReIm[(1 + I)^n] == ReIm[(1 + Sqrt[3] I)^m]
   , Sow[{n, m}]
   ]
  , {n, 100}
  , {m, 100}
  ]
```

> ```
> {{{24, 12}, {48, 24}, {72, 36}, {96, 48}}}
> ```